# Class inside class - Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, class, object, oop

As far as I know `C#` allows you to create classes inside other classes. Why am I getting this error and how it can be fixed? Error: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        class Person {          
            public string Name{ get; set; }
        };
        
        Person person = new Person();
    }
}
```

Comment: class `Person` should be outside `main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can be defined in another class, but not inside a method.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class within some other class. Method cannot contain a class declaration. However you can access other class within a method. You can correct your code as follows;

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Accessing Person Class in Main Method
        Person person = new Person();
    }

    //Class Person within class Program
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    };
}
```

You can learn more about `Nested Classes` from [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-classes-in-c-sharp/)